# Program won't compile: "illegal start of type"

Tags: java

I wrote this program and I keep getting:

> " Grades.java:10: error: illegal start of type"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Grades
{
    final int StudentGrades = 3;

    int total;
    double average;
    int[] GradesArray = new int[StudentGrades];
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < GradesArray.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter grades for Student" + (i+1));
        GradesArray[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        total += GradesArray[i];
    }

        average = total/StudentGrades;

        if(average >= 90 && average <= 100)
          System.out.print("you Got a A");
        else if(average >= 80 && average <= 89)
         System.out.print("you Got a B");
        else if (average >= 70 && average <= 79)
         System.out.print("you Got a C");
        else if (average >= 60 && average <= 69)
          System.out.print("you Got a D");
          else
            System.out.print("you Got a F");

          for(int i = 0; i < GradesArray.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Grades for exam #" + (it1)+"are as follows " + GradesArray[i]);

        }

}
```

Comment: You don't have a method in this class.

Comment: you need a main method in order to compile

Answer (score 1):

You need a starting method that contains everything from your for loop downwards.

Usually:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

}
```